# Migrate columns from table A to table B, and update A with a reference to B

Tags: postgresql, insert, postgresql-11

I have a table A with some columns that need to be migrated to a new table B. But I also need to create a column in table A to reference the id's from the new columns in the table B. I've tried doing it this way but it's not working:

```
WITH cte AS (
INSERT INTO B (c1) 
    SELECT c1
    FROM A
    RETURNING id, A.id as "aId"
)

UPDATE A
SET bId = cte.id 
FROM cte
INNER JOIN A on cte."aId" = A.id
;
```

This is the error message:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table A
LINE 5:  RETURNING id, A.id as "aId"
                       ^
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 168
```

I'm assuming this is because Postgres doesn't allow selecting from the table you are inserting the values and it only allows to return columns from the inserted row.

So how to accomplish this? I know it can probably work with a `for` loop, but is there a cleaner way? I also tried updating table A directly from results of the insertion, but that didn't work as Postgres doesn't allow using the `insert` statement in a subquery for updating.

Comment: Is `a.c1` `UNIQUE NOT NULL`. Please provide *exact* table definitions. If not `UNIQUE`, is it OK to have multiple rows in A point to the same row in B? Or keep a strict 1:1 relationship, even for duplicate values?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter it's not unique, and also it will need to be a 1:1 relationship to allow updates in the future without affecting more than 1 row on table A

Comment: What about the exact table definition? `CREATE TABLE` statement showing data types and constraints. Plus some sample rows to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Expressions in the [`RETURNING` clause of an `INSERT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#id-1.9.3.152.6.2) can ...

> ... use any column names of the table named by ***`table_name`***.

`table_name` being the target table of the `INSERT`.

Assuming `a.c1` is `UNIQUE NOT NULL`, this query works:

```
WITH ins AS (
   INSERT INTO b (c1)
   SELECT c1
   FROM   a
   RETURNING id, c1
   )
UPDATE a
SET    b_id = ins.id 
FROM   ins
WHERE  a.c1 = ins.c1
;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7pIt27A5)

Else, you have to be more specific.

In particular, while the order of rows in an `INSERT` is typically preserved, there is no formal guarantee. So it gets more complicated if `c1` is not `UNIQUE NOT NULL` ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer Erwin, but the c1 column is not unique, there are actually 2 more columns but I've simplified it for the example. All the 3 columns that need to be transferred are non unique nullable strings